# How to use Framelayout with NavigationView from Support Design Library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout, android-design-library, navigationview

How Can I add framelayout with the Navigation View where I am using framelayout as a container for fragments from the drawer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="7dp">

        <android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


        </android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my implementation. Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

This could be a simple implementation, you could check [this post](http://android-developers.blogspot.mx/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) out for more information:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/header_view"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```